# How to store a query result in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTableStatus] 
    @DatabaseName AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'DBA',
    @ProjectID AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'CommandLog'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TableCount as int

    SET @Temp = 'DECLARE @cnt as int;'
    SET @Temp = @Temp + 'USE '+ @DatabaseName +'; SELECT @cnt=COUNT(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME=''' + @ProjectID + ''';'

    PRINT @Temp

    EXEC sp_executesql @temp

    --ASSIGN OUTPUT TO @TableCount
    IF @TableCount > 0  
       -- Do something
END
```

How do I assign the results of `@temp` being executed to variable `@TableCount`?

Comment: Question should be migrated to [dba.se]

Comment: @EvanCarroll why is that ? This seems like a legitimate coding question

Comment: In what sense? You're asking about a question specific to a database, SQL, and the DB's PL. It's a basic DBA skillset.

Comment: @EvanCarroll no, this is not information needed to know by a DBA. This is a question how to extract information from dynamic sql, which qualify as coding. And I was not the one asking the question

Comment: Ok, I disagree. =) Strongly. In fact, in my opinion 100% of your top-20 answers should all be migrated to [dba.se]. Not just is that a better place for the questions, but there are more experts capable of answering them.

Comment: @EvanCarroll seems we can only agree to disagree. Because 95+ % of my answers are not DBA related

Comment: We disagree about that too. It's not an identity, it's a taxonomy. If you're working with a database and nothing external to it, you're in the territory of a DBA. We have a site for that. If you're asking about Ubuntu, we have a site for that. If you're asking about Drupal, we have a site for that too. StackOverflow isn't a dumping ground for material better suited elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTableStatus] 
    @DatabaseName as nvarchar(50) = 'DBA',
    @ProjectID as nvarchar(50) = 'CommandLog'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TableCount as int,@Temp nvarchar(max)='';
--    SET @Temp = 'DECLARE @cnt as int;'
    SET @Temp = @Temp + 'USE '+ @DatabaseName +'; SELECT @cnt=COUNT(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_NAME=''' + 
@ProjectID + ''';'
    print @Temp
    EXEC sp_executesql @temp,
      N'@cnt int out',@TableCount out;
    --ASSIGN OUTPUT TO @TableCount
    IF @TableCount >0 
     -- Do something
        print @TableCount;
END
```

But why not use the [OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function?

Also your code is prone to [SQL-injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get the count from `@temp`, try using an OUTPUT with your dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @temp, N'@cnt int OUTPUT', @TableCount OUTPUT
```

These additions to `sp_executesql` will output the `@cnt` value in your dynamic SQL to the `@TableCount` in your current context.

Answer (score 0):

You can set value as

```
SET @TableCount = @cnt
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: This doesn't store a query result in a variable